# Mapping the URL to the filesytem with nginx rewrites?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I would like to be able to map the pretty URL's to the filesystem of a nginx website. However, I am having trouble figuring out how it would work. I would like to take a url like `/action/method/param/param2/` and map it to `/action/method.php/param/param2`. According to the [nginx docs](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_split_path_info) something like this should work.

```
   location / {
            include fastcgi_params;
            # regex: word / word (followed by anything)
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(\w+/\w+)(.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name.php;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add '/' in first group:

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/\w+/\w+)(.*)$;
```